# How to add set button in a populateViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, fragment

Im having a problem when i added in a Button in the pouplateViewHolder and it has no mistakes, but when i pressed on it, it wont show anything, and it doesnt response. Can anyone please help me, im stucked at this part and stressed of it. Im using android studio and this is inside a recycler view. When i keep pressing the btn, it wont show anything to me, and the database is not updated too.

```
private RecyclerView mRequestsList;

private DatabaseReference mFriendsRequestDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabaseRef;
private DatabaseReference mFriendsReqDatabaseRef;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String mCurrent_user_id;

private View mMainView;

private Button mAcceptReqBtn;


public RequestsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_requests, container, false);

    mRequestsList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.requests_list);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mFriendsRequestDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req").child(mCurrent_user_id);;
    mFriendsRequestDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mFriendsReqDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req");
    mFriendsDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends");

    mRequestsList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    mRequestsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    mAcceptReqBtn = (Button) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.request_accept_btn);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return mMainView;
}


@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Requests, RequestsFragment.RequestViewHolder>RequestsRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Requests, RequestsFragment.RequestViewHolder>
            (
                    Requests.class,
                    R.layout.friend_request_single_layout,
                    RequestsFragment.RequestViewHolder.class,
                    mFriendsRequestDatabase

            ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final RequestsFragment.RequestViewHolder viewHolder, Requests model, int position) {

            final String list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

            DatabaseReference get_type_ref = getRef(position).child("request_type").getRef();

            get_type_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {

                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        String request_type = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                        if(request_type.equals("received"))
                        {

                            mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                    final String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                                    final String userStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();


                                    viewHolder.setName(userName);
                                    viewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());
                                    viewHolder.setUserStatus(userStatus);


                                    mAcceptReqBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view){

                                            final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                                            Map friendsMap = new HashMap();
                                            friendsMap.put("Friends/" + mCurrent_user_id + "/" + list_user_id + "/date", currentDate);
                                            friendsMap.put("Friends/" + list_user_id + "/"  + mCurrent_user_id + "/date", currentDate);


                                            friendsMap.put("Friend_req/" + mCurrent_user_id + "/" + list_user_id, null);
                                            friendsMap.put("Friend_req/" + list_user_id + "/" + mCurrent_user_id, null);


                                            mFriendsReqDatabaseRef.updateChildren(friendsMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {


                                                    if(databaseError == null){

                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Friends Request Accepted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }

                                    });

                                    /*viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view)
                                        {

                                            CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Accept Friend Request", "Cancel Friend Request"};

                                            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                                            builder.setTitle("Friend Req Options");
                                            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                                    //Click Event for each item.
                                                    if(i == 0){

                                                        final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                                                        Map friendsMap = new HashMap();
                                                        friendsMap.put("Friends/" + mCurrent_user_id + "/" + list_user_id + "/date", currentDate);
                                                        friendsMap.put("Friends/" + list_user_id + "/"  + mCurrent_user_id + "/date", currentDate);


                                                        friendsMap.put("Friend_req/" + mCurrent_user_id + "/" + list_user_id, null);
                                                        friendsMap.put("Friend_req/" + list_user_id + "/" + mCurrent_user_id, null);


                                                        mFriendsReqDatabaseRef.updateChildren(friendsMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {


                                                                if(databaseError == null){

                                                                  Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Friends Request Accepted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                                }

                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                    }

                                                    if(i == 1){




                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });

                                            builder.show();

                                        }
                                    });*/

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });


                        }else if(request_type.equals("sent"))
                        {

                            //req_sent_btn = (Button) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.request_accept_btn);
                            //req_sent_btn.setText("Request Sent");

                            //viewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.request_decline_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                    final String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                                    final String userStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();


                                    viewHolder.setName(userName);
                                    viewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());
                                    viewHolder.setUserStatus(userStatus);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



        }
    };

    mRequestsList.setAdapter(RequestsRecyclerAdapter);

}




public static class RequestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    View mView;

    public RequestViewHolder(View itemView)
    {

        super(itemView);

        mView=itemView;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_profile_name);
        userNameView.setText(name);

    }

    public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx) {

        CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_profile_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);

    }

    public void setUserStatus(String userStatus) {

        TextView user_status= (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_profile_status);
        user_status.setText(userStatus);

    }
}
```

This is the XML file. Please help :(

```
<CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/request_profile_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/request_profile_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/display_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/request_profile_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="User Default Status"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/request_accept_btn"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="Accept"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/request_decline_btn"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text="Decline"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The Button might have no focus. You can add descendantFocusablity property to the main layout of recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button should be initialized in viewholder if that is an instance in your recyclerview. Hope the following code will solve your problem.

```
View mView;
Button mAcceptReqBtn;
public RequestViewHolder(View itemView)
{

    super(itemView);
    mView=itemView;
    mAcceptReqBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.request_accept_btn);

}
```

Comment: i have added the xml file for the MainView.

Comment: It seems that your button is in the recyclerview, then it should be initialize in `RequestViewHolder`

Comment: thank you so much and it works! but im having error :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: what i want to do is, when i clicked on that button, and the text of button will be changed.